# Jquery autocomplete styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

While styling the jQuery autocomplete plugin, I get the following HTML code hardwired to my page:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; "></ul>
```

How can I disable styling from being made through HTML and keep it done via CSS? I don't think my CSS files are overwriting that style.

Any help will do

Comment: the plugin likely needs those styles, and is adjusting them to meet the behavior of the plugin.

Comment: I want to separate my result <ul> list display from my search box...any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on *display from my search box*?

Comment: The result list is usually appended to the bottom of my search text box...I want there to be a gap of 5 px, just in between the search text box and the box containing the result list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete needs to set some inline styles to position the drop down list under the text box and size it equally.

It doesn't set anything else, so it's completely up to you to provide visual styling of it by setting styles of those classes that are added to it (ie. `ui-autocomplete`).

### Advice

What I'm trying to tell you is this: set the visual aspects of the drop down list that gets displayed and don't worry about positioning and sizing inline styles.

### Need to change positioning

If you do need to override positioning and sizing of this element you can always set your styles as `!important`.

```
ul.ui-autocomplete
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px!important;
    top: 0!important;
    ...
}
```

### Additional edit

Setting `margin-top` doesn't do anything since it calculates position every single time it displays the drop down. But you can try setting this:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    border-top:5px solid transparent!important;
}
```

This actually does the trick.

Comment: I want to separate my result <ul> list display from my search box...any idea how this can be done?
I just want 5 free px in between

Comment: @Mahmud: Have you tried setting `margin-top: 5px;` to put some space between your search box and the list?

Comment: @Mahmud: You're right. It calculates position every time it displays the drop down so it adjusts it by the margin value as well.

Comment: It's still not working with me, but thanks for the help :) I think there is something else wrong in my environment.

Comment: @Mahmoud: If your background is uniform colour you can set a specific border colour instead of setting it to transparent though.

Comment: @Robert: I adjusted the border of the textbook search and not the autocomplete...it's a weird way to do this, but at least it works :)
I hope someone can come up with a more legit way to solve this...or maybe that's the beauty of CSS

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by implementing some changes in the "open" method of Autocomplete.

consider this example:

```
$('#search_text_box').autocomplete({
        source: "<?= $this->baseUrl('items/autocomplete');?>",
        minLength: 2,
        search: function(){
            //$ulForResults.empty();
        },
        'open': function(e, ui) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('top', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('top')[0] + 4);
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('left', $("ul.ui-autocomplete").cssUnit('left')[0] - 2);
            $('.ui-autocomplete').append("<div id='autofill_results'><span>2,000</span> results found, showing <span>10</span></div>");
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };
```

In this way by changing how and where your autocomplete appears. The 'ul' that shows autocomplete info has class 'ui-autocomplete' you can manipulate its css in this function to show the drop down the way you want.