# autocomplete style for jqGrid and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete

I am using CSS class `ui-autocomplete` (as explained in [theming](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#theming) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5019752/356726)) to adjust my jQuery / jqGrid style. Works fine for the font size, but not for `line-height`.

The `line-height` is still 1.5 (want 1.0), as of the CSS matching in `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a`. I **do not want to override the global jQuery css style**, as it is used elsewhere.

As you can see below, the `line-height` is due to the `li` style, while my font-size change is applied to the surrounding `ul` element. What would be the easiest way to set the `line-height` only for this autocomplete?

[image: CSS hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use !important for CSS property for line-height.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    line-height: xx!important;
}
```

Comment: Good hint, does not work with Chrome in my case, nevertheless was worth a trial.